# Is there a way to remove the special meaning of "\t" in HiveQL?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table (table_1) that has a column (column_1) that contains values of the form **"some_string \t some_other_string"**.

When I do,

```
SELECT column_1 
FROM table_1;
```

string after "\t" is shifted to the right to a new column. Is there a way to avoid this? Is there a way to get the entire **"some_string \t some_other_string"** in the first column itself?

I have tried replacing "\t" with "\\\\t" and it works.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(column_1,"\t","\\\\t")
FROM table_1;
```

I would like to find out if there are any other ways of handling this?

Comment: this is strange. what kind of table are you using could it be that this kind of table considers tab special ... I could not reproduce your example with my setup

Comment: Did you define this table using `FIELDS DELIMITED BY`...? Please show the table description

Comment: @user1102074, I'm using a cornerstone table if that answers your question, I don't know if the issue has anything to do with the table itself, the string is stored correctly in the table, I'm facing this issue only while trying to pull data in hive, I was thinking it has to do something with hive settings.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I did not define this table and the string is stored fine in the table, just that "\t" is being treated as a special character while pulling data in hive. And sorry I won't be able to give much information on the table and data as it belongs to the company I work for. The solution I have mentioned along with the question does work for me, just that I want to know if there is a better solution. Is it possible for me to remove the special meaning of \t in the table as well as in hive?

Comment: It's just a delimiter. You can look at the table definition using `DESCRIBE` query without exposing company data to see something like `STORED AS TEXT LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FIELDS DELIMITED BY '\t'`. Beyond that, you need string parsing functions within each field to do anything. So, if the table should have only a single column, change your field delimiter to a comma or something that doesn't exist in each row